# Stop or release MediaPlayer while it is still preparing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Is it a bug or is it not possible to release, stop or kill `MediaPlayer` while it's preparing?

I have an instance of `MediaPlayer` running in `Service`, it stops fine if I stop, release, set it to null, while `MediaPlayer` is in **prepared state**. But it doesn't if I stop, release, set it to null if it's in **preparing state**.

`onPrepared()` is called after stop, release, setting to null. Some workaround for this?

I think it's common use case when a user wants to stop `MediaPlayer` before it has finished preparing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By looking at the [`MediaPlayer` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop%28%29), you're not allowed to call `stop()` on an uninitialized object; which makes sense because you can't stop what is not running/ready yet.

On the other hand, `release()` seems to do the trick after looking at [the source code of `MediaPlayer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.release%28%29).

But it doesn't harm to add a boolean flag to indicate that there is no need for the `MediaPlayer` object anymore and use that flag to release your object if `onPrepared()` gets called.

A pseudocode would look like this:

```
public void cancel(){
 mCancel = true;
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player){
  if(mCancel){
   player.release();
   //nullify your MediaPlayer reference
   mediaPlayer = null
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution in onPrepared() method.

Comment: It works but at which point we have to set the mCancel to false?

Comment: @Parin Parikh Just after `mediaPlayer = null`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to implement the OnBufferingUpdateListener and override its method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    if (cancel) {
        mp.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;

    }
}
```