# Stop or cancel the VideoView prepared

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

In my example am having a list of video links and next previous buttons. When i click on next the next video from the list get played. My problem is when i click on next `hVideoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath));` get called and it takes some time to get prepare. so in this duration if i again click on next the next video link get called. Mean while if previous video is ready its `OnPreparedListener()` get executed and start the older video. what i want to do is when i click on next the previous all operation should get stopped.
And here is my code

```
public void initializeVideo(final String videoPath)
{
    BaseActivity.ShowLoading(this, "Buffering...");

    hVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lin_webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            hVideoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath));
        }
    });

    hVideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() 
    {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(HighlightsActivity.this);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(HighlightsActivity.this);

            BaseActivity.StopLoadingDialog();
            hVideoview.requestFocus();
            hVideoview.start();
            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = hVideoview.getDuration();
            seek_bar.setMax(mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds);
            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            imgPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

so is there any way to stop `OnPreparedListener()` being executed?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Please check this if it helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544891/mediaplayer-stop-release-while-prepareasync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544891/mediaplayer-stop-release-while-prepareasync)

Comment: Answer here
[Media stop, release while prepareasync](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16545152/1185521)

Answer (score 0):

In `initializeVideo` method add this before `setVideoURI`

```
if (hVideoview.isPlaying()) {
    hVideoview.stopPlayback();
}
```

Comment: but if previous video is not prepared then the if condition will return false.