# How to release media player while preparing

Tags: android, media-player

I am working on music player app where I am doing streaming of music using `MediaPlayer`. Streaming is working fine but now I want If user press back button of the activity then it should stop preparing & release media player immediately.

Currently when it is preparing and if activity is being destroyed then I am releasing the `MediaPlayer` like this but when it release it then it hangs the application & show ANR.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

I am initializing `MediaPlayer` like below

```
mediaPlayer = null;
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://www.samisite.com/sound/cropShadesofGrayMonkees.mp3");
```

Now I want when it start preparing then on back press when I am releasing in `onDestory` then it should not hang the app & release the media player smoothly.

Please help me what is the best way to do this. Thanks in advance
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

Comment: try putting `super.onDestroy();` after you stop and release mediaplayer

Comment: @Lalit Poptani  I just use it but  not working .Application still hangs.

Comment: Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544891/mediaplayer-stop-release-while-prepareasync). And the MediaPlayer State Diagram from android [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java).

Comment: @John  Can you please clear that where to set mCancel flag true?

Comment: I think where you want to stop mediaplayer (in your case is destroy or onBackPress), set it to true. And you need to set OnPreparedListener to your mp.

Comment: @John  `onPrepared` is being called once it is ready to playback but he might be looking for before it is ready to playback or while preparing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544891/mediaplayer-stop-release-while-prepareasync). And the [MediaPlayer State Diagram](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) from android code.

Edit:

@TGMCians I showed him the provided link, So, if the playback is still not ready or preparing, he can not call `stop()` until it's called `onPrepared`. I'm not sure that `onPrepared` keep called after the app `onDestroy` called. So, The full snip I think is:

```
     private boolean mPrepared = false;
     private boolean mCancel = false;
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player){
            mPrepared = true;
            if(mCancel){
                player.release();
                mPrepared = false;
                mCancel = false;
                //nullify your MediaPlayer reference
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        private void cancelMedia(){
            mCancel = true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            cancelMedia();
            if (mediaPlayer != null && mPrepared) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mPrepared = false;
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }
```